# Ocultar columna en una tabla html

Tags: javascript, html, html5, tr

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
<tr>
 <td>Prueba</td>
 <td>Prueba</td>
 <td>Prueba</td>
 <td>Prueba</td>
 <td>Prueba</td>
 <td>Oculta</td>
 <td>Oculta</td>
 <td>Oculta</td>
</tr>
```

Como puedo hacer para que en la vista unicamente se vean las pruebas, y las ocultas, no ?¿

Y que ocupen todo el ancho de la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN :**

Simplemente **añadí** un **style** a cada uno de ellos de esta forma:

```
<td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"> Oculto </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de ir recorriendo todos los elemenentos 'td' e ir revisando sus innerHTML para ocultarlos en caso de que contengan la palabra 'Oculta'

```
for(i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("td").length; i++){
if (document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].innerHTML == 'Oculta'){
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.display='none';
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero ya encontré la solución.